# Python: How do I use the if function when calling out a specific row?

Tags: python, if-statement

This is my data frame (labeled unp):

[data frame unp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o94Gf.png)

```
    LOCATION    TIME    Unemployment_Rate   Unit_Labour_Cost    GDP_CAP PTEmployment    HR_WKD  Collective  IndividualCollective    Individual  Temp    GDPCAP_ULC  GDP_Growth
0   AUT 2013    5.336031    2.632506    47936.67796 19.863556   1632.1  2.14    1.80    1.66    1.47    18209.522774    NaN
1   AUT 2014    5.621219    1.996807    48813.53441 20.939237   1621.6  2.14    1.80    1.66    1.47    24445.794917    876.85645
2   AUT 2015    5.723468    1.515733    49925.22780 21.026548   1598.9  2.14    1.80    1.66    1.47    32938.009399    1111.69339
3   AUT 2016    6.014071    1.610391    50923.69330 20.889132   1609.4  2.14    1.80    1.66    1.47    31621.943553    998.46550
4   BEL 2013    8.425185    1.988013    43745.95156 18.212509   1558.0  2.48    2.22    2.11    1.91    22004.861920    -7177.74174
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
101 SWE 2016    6.991096    1.899792    48690.14644 13.800736   1626.0  2.72    2.54    2.48    1.55    25629.198586    779.74573
102 USA 2013    7.375000    1.099109    53016.28880 12.255613   1782.0  1.33    1.31    1.30    0.27    48235.697096    4326.14236
103 USA 2014    6.166667    2.027852    54935.20048 10.611552   1784.0  1.33    1.31    1.30    0.27    27090.340163    1918.91168
104 USA 2015    5.291667    1.912012    56700.88042 9.879047    1785.0  1.33    1.31    1.30    0.27    29655.086066    1765.67994
105 USA 2016    4.866667    1.045644    57797.46221 9.454144    1781.0  1.33    1.31    1.30    0.27    55274.512367    1096.58179
```

I want to change the row GDP_Growth which is currently blank to have the value of:
unp.GDP_CAP - unp.GDP_CAP.shift(1)

If it fulfils the condition that the 'TIME' is not 2014 or >2014, else it should be N/A

Tried using the if function directly but it's not working:

```
if unp.loc[unp['TIME'] > 2014]:
  unp['GDP_Growth'] = unp.GDP_CAP - unp.GDP_CAP.shift(1)
 else:
return
```

Comment: Use `np.where()` to perform an action on rows where a condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid the `if` statement when using dataframes as it will be slower (less efficient).

In place, depending on what you need, you can use `np.where()`.

because the dataframe in the question is a picture (as opposed to text), i give you the standard implementation, which looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create a sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]})

# Use np.where() to select values from column 'A' where column 'B' is greater than 7
result = np.where(df['B'] > 7, df['A'], 0)

# Print the result
print(result)
```

The result of the above is this:

```
[0, 0, 0, 4, 5]
```

You will need to modify the above for your particular dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

The question in title is currently *Python: How do I use the if function when calling out a specific row?*, which my answer will not apply to. Instead, we will compute the derivate / 'growth' and selectively apply it.

**Explanation**: In Python, you generally want to use a functional programming style to keep most computations outside of the Python interpreter and instead work with C-implemented functions.

**Solution**:
**A. Obtain the derivate/'growth'**
For your dataframe `df = pd.DataFrame(...)` you can obtain the change in value for a specific column with `df['column_name'].diff()`, e.g.

```
# This is your dataframe
In : df
Out:
        gdp growth  year
    0    0   <NA>  2000
    1    1   <NA>  2001
    2    2   <NA>  2002
    3    3   <NA>  2003
    4    4   <NA>  2004

In : df['gdp'].diff()
Out: 
0    NaN
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
4    1.0
Name: year, dtype: float64
```

**B. Apply it to the 'growth' column**

```
In :df['growth'] = df['gdp'].diff()
df
Out: 
   gdp  growth  year
0    0     NaN  2000
1    1     1.0  2001
2    2     1.0  2002
3    3     1.0  2003
4    4     1.0  2004
```

**C. Selectively exclude values**
If you then want specific years to have a certain value, apply them selectively

```
In : df['growth'].iloc[np.where(df['year']<2003)] = np.nan
df
Out:
   gdp growth  year
0    0    NaN  2000
1    1    NaN  2001
2    2    NaN  2002
3    3    1.0  2003
4    4    1.0  2004
```